# Why does reCaptcha need the ip address of the user?

Tags: recaptcha, privacy

reCaptcha requires the ip address of the user who submitted captchaResponse. Does anyone know how reCaptcha uses this information? Recaptcha's website does not give any information on how the user's ip address will be used.
Aren't there any privacy concerns here?

Comment: Probably. But why not take it up with them directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably to enforce [rate limits](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/02/rate-limiting-and-velocity-checking.html), which would be pretty important for something like reCaptcha.